# Proving 2-Dimensional Maps Are Topologically Conjugate

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I am having some difficulty proving the fact that the maps

$$F(v)=\left(\begin{matrix}
1/2&0\\
0&1/2
\end{matrix}\right)v$$

and

$$G(v)=\left(\begin{matrix}
1/4&0\\
0&1/8
\end{matrix}\right)v$$

are topologically conjugate as maps on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I am allowed to use the fact that similar matrices are topologically conjugate and that maps on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=ax$ and $g(x)=bx$ with $0<a<b<1$ are topologically conjugate. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note to others on the site: a definition of topological conjugacy is [given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_conjugacy). To see that the functions $f,g$ given are topologically conjugate, note that $f \circ h = h \circ g$ when we take 
$$
h(x) = \operatorname{sgn}(x) |x|^m, \qquad m := \frac{\log(a)}{\log(b)}.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Rewrite the maps as
$$
F(v) = (f_1(v_1),f_2(v_2)) = \left(\frac 12 v_1,\frac 12 v_2\right)\\
G(v) = (g_1(v_1),g_2(v_2)) = \left(\frac 14 v_1,\frac 18 v_2\right).
$$
We can see that $f_i$ is topologically conjuagte to $g_i$ for $i=1,2$. How does this allow us to answer the question?